# Solving a recurrence relation in series of triangles.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given an equilateral triangle as shown in figure (a), if we draw one line parallel to each side such that the 3 lines divide each side into 2 segments of equal length, then we will get the figure as shown in figure (b). Let us call the triangle in (a) *S0*, the figure in (b) *S1*. Similarly, we can draw k lines parallel to each side such that the *3k* lines divide each side into *(k+1)* segments of equal length. Let us call the figure *Sk*. As an example, figure (c) shows the figure *S2*.

**[Images of *S0. S1. S2*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQahQ.png)**
[image]

Now, we wish to count how many upright triangles are contained in *Sk*. A triangle is called upright if the base is at the lower side. In figure (b), the triangle *abc* in *S1* is not an upright triangle because the line (a, b) is at the upper side of node c. Thus, *S1* contains 4 upright triangles, including 3 smaller ones plus *efg*. It is not difficult to see that *S2* contains 10 upright triangles. Let a be the number of upright triangles that Sn contains. Find a recurrence relation for an and solve it.

### My answer:

I made a relationship of the number of parallel lines to the number of upright triangles. This gave me the following open formula equation. I used that equation to recursively solve for a closed formula. But my final equation falls off and does not match the sequence for some of the numbers. [Pic#1](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/279696522709434378/543084958323834891/IMG_1682.JPG), [Pic#2](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/279696522709434378/543084959728926720/IMG_1683.JPG)
[image]
[image]
I know the final answer is supposed to be $${3n^2+3n+2 \over2}$$

Comment: You have miscounted the number of upright triangles in $S_3$. The correct count is $a_3=20$. Going further: $a_4=35$, $a_5=56$

Comment: @DanielMathias yea youre right. It should be 20 triangles. So my entire formula is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Removing the bottom row from $S_n$ leaves a figure identical to $S_{n-1}$. Therefore,  $a_n-a_{n-1}$ is the number of upright triangles in $S_n$ which are not contained in this upper $S_{n-1}$. In other words, $a_n-a_{n-1}$ counts the number of triangles which lie flat on the bottom of $S_n$. Such a triangle is uniquely specified by its upper vertex; given the upper vertex, you can recover the triangle by drawing sides downwards at $60^\circ$ slopes. Since there are $1+2+\dots+(n-1)=\binom{n}2$ possibilities for this upper vertex, you get
$$
a_n=a_{n-1}+\binom{n}2
$$
This is a non-homogeneous linear recurrence. Can you solve this for $a_n$?